# vi sed or awk. every line in a text file. replace 9 characters starting at position 75

Tags: vim, awk, sed, vi

I have a huge file 
from line 3 to end of (#lines in file -1 )
starting at character position 75 on the line.  I need to change the string to 123456789.

thought suggestions?   I can't the existing characters per line are not duplicates so I can't search on that.

The joys of hiding pii data

Comment: Please provide sample input (small snippet, foobared) and expected output.

Comment: first last                 (space till character 74)  clientId  more stuff

Comment: peter cooke        .......    987654321   ......more stuff

Comment: customer id starts at column 75

Comment: Does vim protest if you just visual block select these columns and do the change that way?  Otherwise, ergonaut's answer seemed to work for the small sample file I generated..

Comment: There is so much of vi / vim I don't know about.  can you point me example of visual block?   Sorry basic simple user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **vim**, you can do this:

```
%s/\(^.\{75\}\)\@<=........./1234567890/g
```

which basically does a lookbehind of 75 characters (which starts at the beginning of the line), and replaces the rest of the line with your string.

Comment: i need exactly 9 characters from position 75 - 84 to change  to 123456789.  everything else needs to remain the same.

Comment: close.  that allowed me to keep the from 74 but lost everything after 84

Comment: I must have had something wrong with my \ ing.  works on mac.  now to see if work on redhat vi.     Also /g  isn't that for global.  since I only want it occur once on a line for that character position.  Should there be a "g" at the end of the pattern?

Comment: It works for me on vim 7.3 (mac), works without a g as well.

Comment: `:%s/\v%75c.{9}/123456789/`.  Vim has lots of helpers like this. `:help pattern`.

Comment: Just an fyi.  in the VI on redhat VM I am using.  the /g option applies to every line.  so if you need to apply the change lines 3 to $-# (example ":3,$-1 s/\(^.\{75\}\)\@<=........./1234567890/ does the right thing but adding /g applies changes to lines 1, 2, and $

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat testfile 
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....ReplaceMeKeep
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....OldData..Keep
```

#### Using sed

This replaces the nine characters starting with column 75 on with `123456789`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{74}).{0,9}/\1123456789/' testfile
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....123456789Keep
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....123456789Keep
```

#### Using awk

This puts the new string in place of the first nine characters starting at position 75:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,74) "123456789" substr($0,75+9)}' testfile
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....123456789Keep
.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-.........-....123456789Keep
```

Comment: the sed is dropping the the first 74 characters.  so I am getting 123456789 at front of line

Comment: awk is dropping everthing after position 84

Comment: @petercooke  (1) Thank you for clarifying that.  Answer updated to keep characters on the longer lines.  (2) I cannot reproduce the sed issue that you describe.